# Verifying Tails ISO problem

Tags: tails

Trying to verify the ISO image using the command line (Terminal in Mac). However, the folder which I saved it to won't allow me to find it.

Instructions:

```
cd [the directory in which you downloaded the key] gpg --keyid-format long --import tails-signing.key
```

What I did:

```
cd [Downloads] gpg --keyid-format long --import tails-signing.key
```

Result:

> --keyid-format long --import tails-signing.keycd [Downloads] gpg: can't open tails-signing.keycd': No such file or directory
>   gpg: can't open[Downloads]': No such file or directory gpg: Total number processed: 0 MacBook-Pro:~ Sello$ gpg --keyid-format long --import tails-signing.key

I also tried the folder name which I saved it to, and desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[` and `]` characters are part of the help/instruction; you should not type them.

And these are actually two commands.

So when the key file is in a folder named `Downloads`, the first command would look like:

```
cd Downloads
```

The second command:

```
gpg --keyid-format long --import tails-signing.key
```

Comment: MacBook-Pro:~ Stello$ cd Downloads
MacBook-Pro:Downloads Stello$ gpg --keyid-format long --import tails-signing.key
gpg: can't open `tails-signing.key': No such file or directory
gpg: Total number processed: 0
MacBook-Pro:Downloads Stello$

Comment: ^Same Situation. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @Macedon93: The key file (`tails-signing.key`) needs to be in the `Downloads` folder. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes it is there in my downloads i can see it clerly

Comment: @Macedon93: And is the case correct? Maybe you have two download folders (`Downloads` and `downloads`)?

Comment: However i do have PGP Keychain Access. Can i use this to verify the image ? Appreciate the help btw

Comment: No only Downloads

Comment: @Macedon93: The two commands in your question are only for importing the key to your keychain. So you could also use a different tool if it supports importing keys.

Comment: Moved ISO to desktop, where it was located via cmd line.